Land Border Crossing in the Balkans
I'm looking to plan a 2 week trip in the Balkans in December. Will be landing in Sarajevo and was hoping to drive through Montenegro, Serbia, and back to Sarajevo. I heard that you need car rental approval for such road trip, but 2 clarifying questions:

Is the border crossing process smooth?
Is the weather condition in December fine for driving? Do I need snow tires?


Border formalities between these three countries are very smooth. We don't know what your nationality is; if it's something more exotic (by Balkan standards), it could take longer, but not much more than a couple of minutes. IMO not many rental companies will let you drive their car across a border, though. Some will, but they may charge extra fees. Be prepared.
Definitely drive on winter tires in December. Balkan countries are quite mountainous and snow in December is not uncommon. A few centimeters of slush can be a showstopper if you have summer tires. Rental cars will most probably have all-season tires (which are acceptable), just don't forget to check it yourself.
